# Reflexive version of $\in$ relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I want to show that $(A,\in)$ is a well-ordered set, if I understand it correctly I should take the reflexive version of $\in$. I.e. for $\subset$ this is denoted by $\subseteq$, but how is this denoted for $\in$? Especially in latex?

Comment: What's a woset?

Comment: Well-ordered set

Comment: Can't you just use the irreflexive (strict) version of well-ordered set?

Comment: @Gerry: It is a set of woes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard symbol for "$\in$ or $=$".  I would suggest simply writing it as $\leq$ in this context (and of course explaining what you mean by $\leq$), assuming you are not using that symbol for anything else.

I would add that it is very common to define well-ordered sets as having a *strict* order relation, and with that definition you don't need to use "$\in$ or $=$" and can just use $\in$ itself.